# Spatie Browsershot not working on Linux server. Getting error sh: node: command not found

Tags: php, node.js, linux, laravel, browsershot

I'm using [Browsershot](https://github.com/spatie/browsershot) on a laravel project. When I use in on localhost it works perfectly.
However, no matter what I do, I can't seem to get it to work on the live server.
I'm running it on a Linux VPS.

Here is my code (within a controller):

```
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Spatie\Browsershot\Browsershot;
use Spatie\Image\Manipulations;

class screenshotController extends Controller
{
    public function take($url){

        $directory = "screenshots/" . date('m') . "/";
        $id = uniqid(). ".jpeg";

        if (!file_exists($directory)) {
            mkdir($directory, 0777, true);
        }

        Browsershot::url("http://".$url)
            ->windowSize(1920, 1080)
            ->fit(Manipulations::FIT_CONTAIN, 525, 394)
            ->noSandbox()
            ->ignoreHttpsErrors()
            ->save($directory.$id);
            return $directory.$id;
    }
}
```

I've tried adding `->setNodeModulePath("/public_html/node_modules/")` as well.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
    (1/1) ProcessFailedException
The command "PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin NODE_PATH='/public_html/node_modules/' node 
'/home/XXXX/public_html/vendor/spatie/browsershot/src/../bin/browser.js' 
'{"url":"http:\/\/xxxxxxx.net","action":"screenshot","options": 
{"type":"png","path":"screenshots\/09\/5d7e151bf330c.jpeg","args":["--no-sandbox"],"viewport": 
{"width":1920,"height":1080},"ignoreHttpsErrors":true}}'" failed.

Exit Code: 127(Command not found)

Working directory: /home/XXXXX/public_html/public

Output:
================


Error Output:
================
sh: node: command not found
```

I'm assuming it has something to do with the npm location or node_modules location.

I saw [this section in the manual](https://github.com/spatie/browsershot#custom-node-and-npm-binaries) :

```
Browsershot::html('Foo')
->setNodeBinary('/usr/local/bin/node')
->setNpmBinary('/usr/local/bin/npm');
```

But I really don't understand how to use it in my situation.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: execute `whereis node` or `whereis nodejs` to get the right path

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I executed both and they both get a blank result. But just to make sure, I ran "node -v" and it got a result.

Comment: what is the result you get when you execute node -v

Comment: v10.16.3
This is on an account within a VPS. Should I have installed node in the root rather than in the actual account?

Comment: I do not think so , I guess that you need to set the path as following `setNodeBinary('/home/user/path/to/node')`

Comment: Apparently something was off with the node installation. I reinstalled it and added ->setNodeBinary("/home/user/bin/node")
        ->setNpmBinary('/home/user/bin/npm')

But now I'm getting some other errors. Seems I don't have Chrome installed (and it's refusing to install normally)

Comment: Any update on this? I think we have the same problem.